# Manejo de recursividad en C

Tags: c

quisiera saber ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Debería devolver:

> En el mes 1 hay 1 pares de conejos.
>
> En el mes 2 hay 1 pares de conejos.
>
> En el mes 3 hay 2 pares de conejos.
>
> En el mes 4 hay 3 pares de conejos.
>
> En el mes 5 hay 5 pares de conejos.

No sé si estoy fallando en la recursividad, lo que me devuelve es:

> Escribe el numero de mes: 5
>
> En el mes 5 habra 0 parejas de conejos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fibonacci(int mes);
int main(){
    int mes;
    printf("Escribe el numero de mes:");
    scanf("%d",&mes);

    printf( "En el mes %d habra %d parejas de conejos.", mes, fibonacci(mes) );

    return 0;
}


int fibonacci(int mes){
    if (mes<=0){
        return 0;
    }else if (mes <= 2){
        return fibonacci(mes - 1);
    }else if(mes<=4){
        return fibonacci(mes - 1) + fibonacci(mes - 2);
    }else{

        return fibonacci(mes - 1) + fibonacci(mes - 2)-fibonacci(mes - 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuál es el problema?...

Comment: Realicé una modificación para entenderlo mejor

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un solo caso base que es 0. No llegarás a ninguna parte si siempre sumas nada.

Si recuerdas la definición de una sucesión recursiva matemática, partes de uno o más elementos iniciales y defines el término enésimo en base a los anteriores.

El caso de la sucesión de Fibonacci es el [siguiente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucesi%C3%B3n_de_Fibonacci#Definici%C3%B3n_recurrente):

- **f0** = 0
- **f1** = 1
- **fn** = f(n-1) + f(n-2)

En el código no es muy diferente. Te falta un caso base, el 1.

Arreglándolo te quedaría una función así de simple:

```
int fibonacci(int mes){
    if (mes <= 0)
        return 0;

    if (mes == 1)
        return 1;

    return fibonacci(mes - 1) + fibonacci(mes - 2);
}
```